# Bootstrap Button group act independently

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a button bar on my web page made with bootstrap.

I have a set of 3 buttons then two. The first three need to be independent. ie I can select one, two or three of them. The second set of two work as required that if one is selected the other is not.

The functionality on the first three do not work and I am not sure why. They are in seperate button groups with different id's

Any ideas? Here is the code:

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top: -4px;">
<div class="col-xs-9" style="padding-right: 0px;">
    <div class="col-xs-4" style="padding: 0px;">
        <div id="openNowBtn" class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="1">
              <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-primary">Open now</button>
              </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4" style="padding: 0px;">
        <div id="freeOnlyBtn" class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="2">
              <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-primary">Free only</button>
              </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4" style="padding: 0px;">
        <div id="18PlusBtn" class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="3">

              <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-primary">18+</button>
              </div>
         </div>      
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-3" style="padding-left: 0px;">
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="...">
      <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-info"><i class="fa fa-th" style="padding-top: 3px; padding-bottom: 3px;"></i></button>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-info"><i class="fa fa-list" style="padding-top: 3px; padding-bottom: 3px;"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: so far I have found this : http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons  under single toggle that uses bootstraps javascript, but it still does not work on the buttons individually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using: [check boxes](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons-checkbox-radio) for multiple, and [radio inputs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons-checkbox-radio) for single.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-xs-9">
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-primary active">
                <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" checked>Open now</label>
            <label class="btn btn-primary">
                <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off">Free only</label>
            <label class="btn btn-primary">
                <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off">+18</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-success">
                <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off">On</label>
            <label class="btn btn-danger">
                <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off">Off</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: works perfect thanks. did not realize you could use them inside a btn group and have them look like buttons

Answer (score 0):

how about this, replace your display text on the buttons with a check box like this:

From:

```
<div id="openNowBtn" class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="1">
              <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-primary">Open now</button>
              </div>
        </div>
```

To:

```
<div id="openNowBtn" class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="1"  data-toggle="buttons">
      <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-primary">
        <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" checked>Display Text
    </button>
      </div>
</div>
```

Worked for me!